# Community wiki posts by deleted users include a broken link

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki, broken-link

When a user makes a community wiki post and later deletes their account, the link to their user is preserved in the author section of the post, for example [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9301/9682) was created by a deleted user and still contains a [broken link to their account](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/209):

[image: Image of a broken link]

I know you can detect when a user doesn't exist as this is the equivalent on a [non-Community Wiki question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/11507/9682):

[image: Image with no broken link]

Can you please make it so there is no user link for deleted users on Community Wiki posts?

Comment: Hah, just realized this on exactly the same question with exactly the same user and even thought about making a meta post for this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)-ish.

Starting with the next build, we'll be properly rebuilding that little summary block when a user is deleted.  However, old posts affected with this issue will stay how they are; as it's kind of a pain to find them all, and they are relatively rare.

Comment: `it's kind of a pain to find them all, and they are relatively rare` But you can manually fix that one on Movies & TV, as I've already found it for you, right? ;)

Comment: @MrLore sure, the manual fix is something any user with edit privileges can do.  Any sort of body edit will cause that to be re-built.  I wouldn't go too crazy with it though.